# How to delete last digit of the variable if I meet 10 or 20?

Tags: linux, bash

Please see above code:
I wish to ping even ip address such as:

> 192.168.1.102, XXX.XXX.XXX.104, XXX.XXX.XXX.108......XXX.XXX.XXX.120.

but I meet on the problem is I set my variable only to let digit. How am I going to change if it meet **10**, and **20** it will help to add. for example my code:

if `$i` meet on **192.168.0.10**, it will not print **192.168.0.10**, it will print **192.168.0.1010**.

How am I going to delete the **0** if it meet **10** or **20**?

```
for((i=2; i<=20; i=i+2 ));
do
    #echo $i
    ip=192.168.1.10$i
    echo $ip
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ for i in $(seq 102 2 120)
> do
>     echo "192.168.1.${i}"
> done

192.168.1.102
192.168.1.104
192.168.1.106
192.168.1.108
192.168.1.110
192.168.1.112
192.168.1.114
192.168.1.116
192.168.1.118
192.168.1.120
```

Or you can modify your code as below:

```
for((i=102; i<=120; i=i+2 ))
do
    ip="192.168.1.${i}"
    echo $ip
done
```

Answer (score 3):

You can perform arithmetic inside of `$((...))`.

```
ip=192.168.1.$((100+i))
```